# java.io.InvalidClassException even with serialVersionUID

Tags: java, serialization, rmi, java-io

I am new to RMI. From the java docs i found that InvalidClassException is thrown when serial version is not matched among local and remote file. But i wrote a dummy class which always throws a InvalidClassException even though statically created serialVersionUID

```
  package com.sac.serialization;

  import java.io.*;
  import java.util.*;

  class ClassA // non-serializable parent class
  {
      String parentname;

      // absence of no-arg constructor
      ClassA(String name) {
          parentname = name;
      }
  }

  class ClassB extends ClassA implements Serializable {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      ClassB(String name) {
          super(name);
      }
  }

  public class ClassC {
      public static void main(String args[]) {
          ClassB c1 = new ClassB("Sachin");
          try {
              ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
                  new FileOutputStream("employee.dat"));
              out.writeObject(c1);
              out.close();

              ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
                  new FileInputStream("employee.dat"));
              ClassA p = (ClassB) in.readObject();
              in.close();
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  }
```

Can some body help me find the root cause?

Comment: **Please post the stack trace in your question.** It should have been included in the first place. The text of the error message will tell you exactly what is invalid about the class.

Answer (score 2):

`ClassA` must have an accessible constructor wth no arguments. The nearest non-serializable base class of a serializable class must have a constructor with no arguments that is accessible to the derived class. See the [Serialization Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#4539).